# Button layout changes when starting emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

[This is what it shows on the emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9iS9.png)

[This is how it is on the Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9Zgn.png)

When ever i start the emulator, the size and positioning of the buttons all change.. Does anyone know why this happens? I'm pretty new to this, so I'm pretty sure that I'm making some mistakes here. Would love some help, let me know

This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static Button button_sbm;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        OnClickButtonListener();
    }

        public void OnClickButtonListener() {
            button_sbm = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
            button_sbm.setOnClickListener(
                    new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://google.com/");

                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                        startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: First it's really a bad idea to place the buttons this way. Try to use 3 horizontal linearlayouts and place your buttons inside. And are you sure the emulator is the same as the phone preview with the xml? And to put the long strings on two lines, add a "\n" in the android:text

Comment: I'm sure the emulator is the same yes. Should i remove the Relative layout, and replace that with 3 horizontal ones? Or just keep the relative, and add horizontals?

Comment: Exactly what answered megha jagdale

Comment: Yeah thanks, do you also know the question i asked after that? When i make an activity on button 2, it works when i click on button 7, not on 2.

Comment: To go to an activity clicking on a button, you need to put an android:onclick parameter and use it in java. Show me how do you start an activity on a button click?

Comment: I added the code , its on the bottom of the question under the other code

Comment: Also want to say that it works, and it worked before the changes, just not on the right button now

Comment: I've added an answer

Comment: Thanks for everything. Another question if i may ask. I want to make another activity on a button, but don't know where to place it. Where do i need to write the activity, and do i need to just type the public voids over, or can i do it inside the same public void?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
I have changed your layout plz refer this

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.rodekruis.MainActivity">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button10"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:text="Nieuws" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button10"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="  Afspraak   maken" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button8"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="  Bezoek  tijden" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button9"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Contact" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="  Geef je mening!" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text=" Route begeleiding" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Specia-listen" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="BWC" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Agenda" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Praktische
 informatie" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, really appreciate it! The layout is fixed and looks great. The only thing that changed is that I made an activity on the "Nieuws" Button. When I clicked on that, i got referred to a webpage. Now that doesn't work anymore, while then name of the button never changed.

Comment: I found out that it sees button 7 as button 2. and button 7 and button 6.. When i use an activity on button 2 and use a link to that, i start the emulator, and when i click button 2 it won't work, but when i click button 7, it does work. They switched or something, do you know why?

Comment: add button attribute  "android:clickable="true"

Comment: Thanks for everything. Another question if i may ask. I want to make another activity on a button, but don't know where to place it. Where do i need to write the activity, and do i need to just type the public voids over, or can i do it inside the same public void?

Answer (score 0):

Answer to the question about the onclick :

you should put an onclick attribute to your buttons:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button10"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:onclick="button2click"
        android:text="Nieuws" />
```

and do like this in your java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static Button button_sbm;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    }

    public void button2click (View v)
        {
             Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://google.com/");

             Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
             startActivity(intent);
        }
}
```